# How to read Russian characters from a database?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, character-encoding, delphi-7, ado

I have a database in SQL Server.

I have a table `Demo` where I inserted text in Russian into a column of type `Nvarchar`

Now I want to read the Russian text into my Delphi app where I want to store it into a string.

Do I have to set any Charset property of ADO query etc. ?

Any other ideas would be welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some tracks here, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819406/how-to-use-delphi-xes-tencoding-to-save-cyrillic-or-shiftjis-text-to-a-file

Comment: @DavidBrabant : that is for delphi XE, not delphi 7

Comment: @CyprUS - yes, but in the comments for that question they also mention `WideCharToMultiByte` which should guide you to a solution.

Comment: @DavidBrabant : Please post your comment as an asnwer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no answers to this one , i will answer it myself . Using  `SetThreadLocale(<language id>)` i was able to set the thread's language id to 1033 ( for english) . Since my DB was set to 1033 id , the displayed text is now correctly displayed . I hope it helps others.

To correctly enter Unicode characters to database , use the prefix `N` for columns where unicode strings are to be entered. For more details , have a look [here](http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html)

Comment: Will there be no other language than Russian in your DB?
`NVarchar` is Unicode. you should read and write `WideString` to and from the DB. It's hard work with D7, I know. but ADO if fully capable to work with Unicode, and for the DB aware controls you could use Tnt Controls for example.